# UA User Report is almost double the GA4' report

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've been tracking my website with a GA4 property for a while now, and with enough data to compare to the UA property, I noticed that UA users report is almost double the GA4 report.
I've search about this and founded that GA4 is more focused on events than sessions, but even when I look up on Event tab, the event count is not as high either.
I've also seen other people with the same problem as me but never found the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi there, I'm giving some steps to debug a very similar issue further. You would just need to flip the circumstance here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605338/is-it-okay-that-ga4-users-doubles-the-universal-analytics-users-numbers/75606392#75606392 Don't want to repost the answer, but do some debugging and update your original question with the findings so that we could help you further.