# Is it okay that GA4 Users doubles the Universal Analytics Users' numbers?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I understand the differences in both. However, such difference cannot be that high. Myfirst intuition is that the results are being duplicated. For instance and checking the same period of time,
UA users:17.748
GA4 users: 36.179

Do you perhaps have any clue why this may be happening? Based on normal behavior if GA4 has more users that would be okay below a threshold of <30%.

I have tried to check if there is somehow a duplicated GA4 code in the website but there is not.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not okay and it's indicative of a problem. Even 30% Would be worth debugging.
Let's do some quick steps of debugging:

1. Make sure you don't have filters in your UA property.
2. Make sure you're comparing the same time periods.
3. Pull all hostnames for the period. Make sure you're not tracking more sites with GA4 than UA.
4. Make sure app tracking is not contributing to your counts in GA4, check the measurement ids that send traffic to the property. UA won't normally accept mobile app traffic.
5. Do the 3 but for pages. Maybe certain sections of the site aren't covered with UA, but are covered by GA4.

That's it, I'm out of ideas for now. Even if you have troubles in tracking, it's pretty difficult to overcount the users. You'd have to really try for it to work.

But just in case, install the Adswerve's datalayer debugger extension and inspect what's firing on pages. Note that GA4 events are batched, so you would need to go inside the event and make sure it's not doubled with a different client id. Although, again, it's quite difficult to do.

Comment: Thanks BNazaruk. I already did some of those test. For instance, 

1. I am aware it tracks more subdomains and traffic. Therefore, I filtered only the main domain for the tests. Same period of time. We do not have an app therefore it does not impact. and finally, checking specific pages is definitely a good idea. I will check it right away. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also take a look at your Measurement IDs. Sometimes there's a stream of data into GA4 that you don't count on.

Comment: I checked all of the options mentioned and I noticed that in the debug view the information is tracked properly but when filtering the real time data the views per page title appears twice. I have been researching the why behind it and so far no luck. 

Thanks for the heads up. I will also take a look into Measurement IDs

Answer (score 0):

I agree with BNazaruk but would suggest if you are looking at daily data and are based in the states its probably a UTC vs EST time zone challenge so check that first.

After completing steps 1-5 if you have not found your answer I would then run a report on page views, sessions and Total users* . If all 3 metrics are up by around 30% you have a data capture issue.  If the views match but the session and total users are higher you are probably including none website data and if the views and sessions match but users do not its probably to do with the lookback window being different between the 2 reports.

*GA4 counts active users GAU counts Total Users You can compare Total Users from UA to Total Users in GA4 by using Explorations in GA4 to find your total users number. These numbers may be more comparable than the Users metrics in the GA4 reports due to the differences in definitions.

Comment: Thank you Max. I already did some test following BNazaruk suggestions. At first glance, the difference doing the exploration report is too high to just be a mere discrepancy. I am going to to the analysis you mentioned but my intuition is that we have a tracking problem.

Comment: In my ignorance, what do you mean by none website data?

Comment: App data, GA4  tracks App usage while GAU did not, so depending on how you have it set up a session can be created on your App but not trigger a page view event and this would be seen in GA4 and not GAU. If the tracking is set up correctly the views will be higher as well.

Comment: Thaks for the explanation. I have checked all possible scenarios and everything points to duplicate information. I am investigating now why it is happening since everything is managed through tag manager. That makes it more strange.